# the listbox is showing "System.Windows.Controls.listboxitem" before file name

Tags: c#

When i want to make the listbox listing an item is showing "system.windows.controls.listboxitem" before the file name

i tried to use Path.GetFileName but is not working

```cs
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\media-directory", "*.mp3", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            foreach (string f in files)
            {
                string entry = Path.GetFileName(f);
                var item = new ListBoxItem() { Content = entry, Tag = f };
                listBox1.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }

        private void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var selectedItem = listBox1.SelectedItem as ListBoxItem;
            string path = selectedItem.Tag.ToString();
            mediaplayer.URL = path;
        }
```

i expect the output to be only the file name!

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page!

Comment: Always avoid mixing WPF classes and Winforms code.  ListBox uses the object's ToString() to display the item you add, ListBoxItem does not override it.  The universal solution is to strongly separate the view from the model, create a List that stores the other info you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define your own class for item object and override the `ToString()` function.
Your items will appear in the `ListBox` according to `ToString()` function return value.

```
    public class PathItem
    {
        public string Path { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Path;
        }
    }
```

When adding a new items, use:

```
listBox1.Items.Add(new PathItem() { Path = Path.GetFileName(f) });
```

In order to get the selection:

```
private void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var selectedItem = listBox1.SelectedItem as PathItem;
    string path = selectedItem.Path;
    mediaplayer.URL = path;
}
```

Comment: thanks, is working but the mediaplayer now is not playing

Comment: Ok, please ask this as a separate question. Provide a code sample, how do you try to play the media... TNX

Comment: i can t i reached the limit for today